# Which task scheduler is used by default when starting/running/invoking tasks in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, task, task-parallel-library

Which task scheduler is used when I start tasks from a task that was run with a specific scheduler?

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(A, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, new MyTaskScheduler());

// ...

void A()
{
    // 1
    Parallel.Invoke(sometasks);

    // 2
    Task.Run(sometask);

    // 3
    Parallel.For(/*...*/);

    // 4
    // Any other task execution that isn't specifying a scheduler explicitly
}
```

Do all example will be scheduled by MyTaskScheduler? I want to use the QueuedTaskScheduler ([From ParallelExtensionsExtras](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/parallelextensionsextras-tour-7-additional-taskschedulers/)) to handle priorities and concurrency limitations for complex web api requests (which may start tasks and/or use other TPL functionality).

Comment: The default *task scheduler* is used regardless of which *task scheduler* is associated with the *current thread* in child TPL methods (as shown) AFAIK

Comment: @MichaelRandall So this statement in the linked blog post is just wrong? "Both tasks and the parallel loops they contain will be limited to a maximum concurrency level of four."

Comment: Stephen is passing the *task scheduler* into the `Parallel.For` options, you are not

Comment: @MichaelRandall thanks, I'm an idiot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to most *TPL* methods, the rule-of-thumb is the default *task scheduler* is used regardless of which *task scheduler* is associated with the *current thread* unless you have explicitly told it otherwise.

You will find most methods will either take *options* which will have a *task scheduler* property or you can supply one in the method itself as on overload